# Simple JSON and Breeze resulting in error to "call fetchMetadata first"

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have an API endpoint that spits out simple JSON like this:

```
{
  "num_results": 2,
  "objects": [
    {
      "creator": null,
      "id": 1,
      "image": "www.test.com",
      "title": "test",
      "user_id": null
    }
}
```

I want to use Breeze to put this into Knockout observables. I gather that I need a custom `jsonResultsAdapter`. I've tried to follow along with the Edmunds example but I admit I don't really get it.

```
var jsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
    name: "test",

    extractResults: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;
        if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
        return results;
    },

    visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
        // Make parser
        if (node.objects) {
            return { entityType: "Pin"  }
        }
      }
    });

var dataService = new breeze.DataService( {
        serviceName: "api/",
        hasServerMetadata: false,
        jsonResultsAdapter: jsonResultsAdapter,
});    

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager( {
  dataService: dataService
});

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery.from("pin");

manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
    ko.applyBindings(data);
}).fail(function(e) {
    alert(e);  
});
```

But this fails inside the executeQuery function with a message:

> Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Pin'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.

I thought I had just done that. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT

```
  function initialize(metadataStore) {
    var DT = breeze.DataType; // alias

    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Pin",
        namespace: "test",
        dataProperties: {


            creator:    { dataType: DT.String },
            id:         { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
            image:      { dataType: DT.String },
            title:      { dataType: DT.String },
            modelLinks: { dataType: DT.Int64 }
        },
    });
  }
```

Got it partially figured out.  Needed to add a metadataStore to describe the type of data coming back.  But now I get

> Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Comment: Your last error has nothing to do with Breeze, that is a Knockout.js issue.

Comment: I realize that, but I suspect it has something to do with how breeze creates the objects from JSON that is causing the issue. I'm starting to believe that breeze doesn't buy you anything unless you have an odata endpoint. It's certainly not saving me LOC over creating individual ko observables. Probably more in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `JsonResultsAdapter` is not doing what you think it should be doing. You should debug into it to see what's going on.

Also check the data returned to the success callback of your query. Do the objects in `data.results` look right to you? Do they have an `entityAspect` property? An `entityType` property? If not, the data did not become entities and I don't think they're going to have observable properties either.

I believe you'll trace your problems to the `visitNode` method. When you get a match on `node.objects`, I predict the node itself will be something like this:

```
{
  "num_results": 2,
  "objects": [
    {
      "creator": null,
      "id": 1,
      "image": "www.test.com",
      "title": "test",
      "user_id": null
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

You're response of

```
return { entityType: "Pin"  }
```

seems to be telling Breeze that ***this entire thing*** should be treated as data for the `Pin` type.

That is obviously not so. The `Pin` data are *inside* the `objects` array.

You actually want to match on those data. You can do that with a test like

```
if (node.id && node.title) {
    return { entityType: ...  } // see below
}
```

or something like that.

The risk is that such a test would match with data for some type other than `Pin`. It would be so *much* easier if your server could serialize a type indicator with the data.

> We did this in [our rails sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/ruby/CCJS-Ruby). We [added a `$type` property](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/ruby/CCJS-Ruby/rails/app/views/breeze/sessions/index.rabl) to each entity object serialized to a Breeze client and set it to the name of the type. That made it easy to identify the node.

### You must return an `EntityType` not the name of the type

Look at the implementation of the ["webApi" DataServiceAdapter](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.webApi.js#L76).

You'll see that you **do not return the *name* of the type**. You return the matching **`EntityType`**.

You'll need code sort of like this:

```
var type = mappingContext.entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Pin', true);
return { entityType: type  }
```

I'm sure you can imagine a more efficient ways to cache this type object so that you don't have to work so hard to get it every single time you visit the node.

### Why specify the type's *namespace*?

You defined your `Pin` type with a namespace of "test". Why? Is that the namespace on the server? Or did you just make it up? You don't need one if you don't have one. It just adds unneeded complexity.

You might get away with this:

```
var DT = breeze.DataType; // alias

metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Pin",
    dataProperties: {
        creator:    { }, // string is the default
        id:         { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
        image:      { },
        title:      { },
        modelLinks: { dataType: DT.Int64 }
    },
});
```

### A better *extractResults* function?

You might also consider refining the `extractResults` method so that it gets rid of extraneous stuff right off the bat. Why not just go right to the `objects` level like this?

```
extractResults: function (data) {
    var results = data.results && data.results.objects;
    if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results.objects' property");
    return results;
}
```